# Impact of FTL on Humanity & discovering new intelligent life

Tags: warfare, humans, faster-than-light, shipbuilding

Let's say Humanity develops FTL in the next 25 years, something along the lines of the [Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) humanity in 2041 still has quarrels amongst themselves.  Our first exploration vessel is launched in the year 2043, and 2-4 years after said event the vessel finds other intelligent life forms.

I'm curious about the following:

- What is the impact of finding said life form(s) on humanity?
- Would it end the quarrel which humanity has had amongst themselves?
- Would chaos ensue?
- What are the chances on said life form of being hostile towards us?
- If said life form is hostile, what would we do against possible retaliation?
- Which planet within 2-4yrs distance are we most likely to find Intelligent life upon?

Speed of the Alcubierre Drive used by humanity is roughly warp 5. (warp 5 is roughly 1.25c)

The alien life is roughly 250 years ahead of mankind, and is a reptilian humanoid, they require a warm environment to thrive, temperatures roughly the same as the Sahara Desert on earth.

The intentions of mankind are to explore, trade and learn, the reptilians are more aggressive than your average humanoid, and will go to great lengths to protect what is theirs.

Comment: I think you have two questions here.  How would humanity react.  and how would the aliens react.

Comment: This is a little broad. You ask if they will be hostile, but we know nothing about them, also, we don't know any of the humans' actions, or wether it could antagonize them. In fact, you don't specify that the alien life _isn't_ human. You just say other intelligent life. You also give distance in years. Do you mean light years?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon I'll edit my question with more detail.

Comment: @bowlturner, Two? I'm counting six!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the impact of finding said life form(s) on humanity?

On humanity as a whole, we would know we are not unique in the universe and there are others out there to either share/compete with.

> Would it end the quarrel which humanity has had amongst themselves?

Yes and no.  We would likely have fewer issues with each other based on things like gender, sexual orientation and race.  However, it would likely create more issues based on ideologies.  Some religions would try to convert them by force if necessary, others would try to enslave them.  Others would see them as a trading partner sell stuff to.  And of course plenty would want to be 'friends' in one way shape or form.

> Would chaos ensue?

There would certainly be areas where the news of such a discovery would cause rioting in the streets. But I expect most people would be more interested in learning about them. (at first any way)

> What are the chances on said life form of being hostile towards us?

Well with your edit to describe the aliens, it would depend on who made first contact.  Someone who thinks they can plant a flag and claim areas are likely to start a conflict.  Those wanting contact and exchange of ideas, might do better, but any contact between two cultures that have nothing in common are likely going to cause some major misunderstandings and possibly lots of trouble.

> If said life form is hostile, what would we do against possible retaliation?

Well first, we'd try to keep our home location secret.  If they don't know where we came from, then they can't attack us.

> Is there a planet we could reach at 1.25c within 2-4yrs time?

According to [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_terrestrial_exoplanet_candidates) the closest likely habitable planet is about 12 ly away.

Comment: Is there a planet we know of that we could reach at 1.25c within 2-4yrs time, that could sustain said alien life?

Comment: @Gerwin Looks like the nearest most likely one is about 12 ly out